# How to put 50% for width

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview

I have a LinearLayout in horizontal orientation and 2 ImageView and I want to make that ImagesView fill 50% of the screen on width, to work in every cellphone or tablet with diferent sizes.

Something like this:

```
 +-------------+   
 |_____________|     
 |      |      |  
 | 50%  | 50%  |  
 |      |      |   
 |-------------|
 |             |
 +-------------+
```

Best so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_animado" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_t"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_animado2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Each ImageView should have `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `androdi:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Use android:layout_weight="" .

Comment: Thx @SherifelKhatib Solve my problem =DD.

Comment: @user1744952 lol good point! I thought it was `androdi:layout_weight=""` :P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Write following code to do that in both views inside `LinearLayout`.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Thanks Chintan that was very helpful =D.

Comment: @Guilherme its my pleasure... :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_c"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_animado" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_t" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"    
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        android:src="@drawable/logo_animado2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use  android:weightSum and android:layout_weight**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_c"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_animado" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_t"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_animado2" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` in both the `ImageView` and make the width if image view as `fill_parent` I think it will solve your problem

But remember it will stretch your image as because image view will streach in every screen resolution so as your image.