# Placing two images to occupy the entire screen

Tags: android, view, android-imageview

I would like to place two images in the respective image views so they occupy the entire screen. So far I have only gotten here :( (To add the device being tested I use an S3)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView                
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/blue"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_below="@id/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The images are 1080 X 1920 and scaled to screen. The problem is either the image below is scaled improperly or they dont connect properly. I have a black area on the top and bottom

I am sorry but the Images are not of the same size.

Comment: Take a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773039/how-to-put-50-for-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/up" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The images are not of same size I should have added this before.

Comment: This is not an issue you can set the scaleType for the images. if you want you can set the height values as your wish. One more addition set the orientation type for the linear lay out

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding weightSum. Replace this xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/white"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/white"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:src="@drawable/blue" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it would look like as:
[image]
for more help.please add comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a LinearLayout with `layout_weight` set:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/up" />

<ImageView                
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/blue"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_below="@id/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For the scaling issue, I'd recommend looking into [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)