# Set recyclerview width to 50% of screen width without breaking recycling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to place two layouts containing RecyclerViews side by side, so that they have the same width and fill their parents, i.e. each one should have 50% of its parent's layout width.

Usually you set [layout_weight for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773039/how-to-put-50-for-width), but layout_weight [does not work with RecyclerViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488894/recyclerview-onbindviewholder-called-for-all-items-when-inside-linearlayout-with/43488723) on old devices. If layout_weight is set, it stops recycling and just creates all views for all items at once, which is too slow, especially on old devices.

What are the alternatives?

I use Jetpack 1.1.0. Perhaps the issue has been fixed in 1.2.0?

Is there some other layout xml attribute for half-width?

Do not use the xml layout and set layoutparams in code to screen width / 2?

Change the item count, so that the adapter only has the visible items, and somehow new items are added, when the user scrolls down in the view?

Comment: you can setup a guideline at 50% and constraint the RecyclerViews to it

Comment: with the androidx.constraintlayout package? That might work. But I have not included that library in my app. It might be overkill to add a new dependency for this issue

Comment: After trying various layout settings, I might have found one that does not have problems. `android:layout_width="10dp"` rather than `android:layout_width="0dp"` on the first child with layout_weight